# What's the purpose of enclosing razor strings with @("<foo>")?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

I'm looking at someone else's HTML (in a .NET web application) and keep seeing code that looks like the following:

```
@("<foo>")
```

But it seems that this could simply be written as `foo` and achieve the same result. I'm assuming that this is razor syntax, but I don't understand the purpose of enclosing a string with `@(" ")`.

Can anyone explain this? A clear answer has been surprisingly difficult to find using Google.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably to keep `<foo>` from being interpreted as a tag.

Comment: Actually, the opposite. It's meant to allow `<foo>` to be output to the page as a tag without affecting the Razor parser. @Carl's answer below is pretty much spot on, but I've seen this most used with forloops where you want to close and reopen an outer tag after a certain number of iterations, for example.

Comment: FWIW, all of the following will serve the  same purpose: `@("<foo>")`, `@Html.Raw("<foo>")`, `@:<foo>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible reason would be to allow closing a tag in multiple places e.g.

```
<div>
@(if foo == bar)
{
    //some content here
    </div>

}
else
{
    //some other content here
    </div>
}
```

Is not valid razor syntax where as

```
@Html.Raw("<div>")
@(if foo == bar)
{
    //some content here
    @Html.Raw("</div>")

}
else
{
    //some other content here
   @Html.Raw("</div>")
}
```

is valid.

Comment: This can be avoided by simply moving the `</div>` out of the conditional block.

Comment: Yes it can - it is just a possible explanation of usage.

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement to my comment above, here's an example of using it inside a for loop:

```
<div class="row">
@for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    if (i != 0 && i % 3 == 0)
    {
        @("</div><div class='row'>")
    }

    <div class="col">@i</div>        
}
</div>
```

Which would roughly produce:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">1</div>
    <div class="col">2</div>
    <div class="col">3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">4</div>
    <div class="col">5</div>
    <div class="col">6</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">7</div>
    <div class="col">8</div>
    <div class="col">9</div>
</div>
```